# change run from script path in automator

Tags: bash, macos, applescript, automator

First of all, my OSX is 10.14.4 and i had bash v3 built in OSX, recently i updated to bash v5 through brew. 
and i did change default by chsh -s /usr/local/Cellar/bash/5.0.3/bin/bash
everything else works fine except some apple workflow/script which utilize "Run from script"

when i try to switch from v3 to v5 in automator, there isn't any option. 
[image]

so my question is that does anyone know how to add new bash option to automator?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to edit your `Shells.plist` file which can be found at:

```
/System/Library/Automator/Run\ Shell\ Script.action/Contents/Resources/Shells.plist
```

Add these following lines :

```xml
<key>/usr/local/Cellar/bash/5.0.3/bin/bash</key>
<dict>
    <key>args</key>
    <array>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>%</string>
        <string>-</string>
    </array>
    <key>script</key>
    <array>
        <string>cat</string>
        <string>for f in "$@"&#10;do&#10;&#09;echo "$f"&#10;done</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Comment: this is great, but i just added to Shells.plist and automator is giving error: cannot load due to invalid signature, any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: You can try this `sudo /usr/libexec/repair_packages --repair --standard-pkgs --volume /` Hope that will help

Comment: repair_packages command no longer exists in Sierra. what choices I have ?

Comment: you could remove the System Integrity Protection, but I'm not sure that will help https://www.imore.com/how-turn-system-integrity-protection-macos

Comment: I did csrutil disable before I made changes to Shells.plist, because if not disabled, I couldn't even make any changes

Comment: ok, in the end, I restored file from Time Machine but I replaced /bin/bash with a shortcut to bash v5. now it's working fine